# Select statement to return one value or another one if the first one is null

Tags: db2

I have a Book's table as follows:

```
id     locale     name         book_id     ...
1      "en-GB"    The book     421
2      "fr-FR"    Le livre     421
...
```

I need to SELECT the book's name for a given locale (for instance 'fr-FR') but then, if the first one is not set, then retrieve the name with the locale by default ('en-GB') which will be always set.
How could I do that?
I'm using a DB2.
I've tried the following statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN B.NAME IS NOT NULL THEN B.NAME ELSE A.NAME END AS NAME FROM BOOK A JOIN BOOK B ON B.BOOK_ID = A.BOOK_ID WHERE A.LOCALE =  "en-GB" AND B.LOCALE = "fr-FR"
```

However, this is only working when both locales are defined, but not in case that I need (when the second locale is not set).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT WITH MY OWN ANSWER:
I have finally used an UNION to achieve that:

```
SELECT NAME FROM BOOK WHERE BOOK_ID = 421 AND LOCALE = "en-GB"
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME FROM BOOK WHERE BOOK_ID = 421 AND LOCALE = "fr-FR"
FETCH  FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Comment: Different id´s? How can you then find the same book in different languages?

Comment: Excuse me, I had copied just a part of the table, there's a bookId field that is used to look for the same book. Thank you very much for your answer, I have edited the question

Comment: Take a look at window functions!

Comment: @FVod If you don't use ordering, then the result of such a select statement with union all may be not stable...

Comment: You're right, ORDER BY is required. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from mytable
where book_id=421 and locale in 
--('*', 'en-GB')
('fr-FR', 'en-GB')
order by case when locale='en-GB' then 1 else 0 end
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 0):

I said View in my previous answer I meant Stored Procedure.
You might want to take a look to creating a Stored Procedure. In a SP you can add if else statements.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProcedure
AS
BEGIN
    IF Exists(SELECT 1 FROM Book WHERE locale = "en-GB")
        SELECT * FROM Book WHERE locale = "fr-FR"
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM Book WHERE locale = "en-GB"
END
```

Something like this.

Comment: You don't need a view to use case expressions.

Comment: How could I use a case expression here? Because the case depends on the result by two different "WHEREs" the LOCALE = "fr-FR" and LOCALE="en-GB"